# unable to load template for CiviEvent Event Management

Tags: civievent, templates, angular

Has anyone encountered this error from CiviEvent "Manage Events" -> "Configure" -> "Info and Settings"?

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl'
```

We're running CiviCRM 5.69.2 with all extensions up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the extension [CiviVolunteer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer) and [Angular profiles](https://civicrm.org/extensions/angular-profile-utilities) to latest.

Comment: Thanks, but according to System Status all extensions, including CiviVolunteer (at 2.4.4) and Angular Profiles (at 6.2.4), are up to date.